# Do network providers object to GSM sleep-wake-sleep cycles of minutes?

Tags: mobile, arduino, gsm

Building a GSM+GPS tracking device with a GSM+GPS breakout and an Arduino Trinket PRO 3V, that will receive SMS now and then to control it, and sending out SMS now and then. It will be on/off sleeping to save the LiPo battery.

The GSM can be put to sleep using "slow clock" settings, or even switching off the RF functions. However, that will make the GSM lose contact with the network, to re-establish contact again some time later when the device wakes up.

That will result in a cycle of contacting the network every, say, 5 minutes for a minute, then sleep again, and lose contact, etc.

Will network providers hate me for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just doing this with one or two devices then the network operators will not even notice.

If you are planning to do it with many thousands of devices then they may but most understand this is a cachet of life and it is the way many IoT devices are going so they are already looking at ways to handle this - there have been trials of devices which are designed to do exactly this type of deep sleep or both LTE and GSM.